# Copy just the values of a cell, not paste

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am attempting to create a command button that will run a script to copy just the values of a cell. As of right now, I have a macro that sets the cells equal to a formula. When I copy the cells, it wants to copy the formula, not the values. I want this button to ONLY copy the values of the range to the clipboard to be copied to a different worksheet. Here is a code I have thus far.

This part of the code is used to formulate the cells.

```
Dim LookupRange As Range
Dim c As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set LookupRange = Range("C9:C300") ' Set range in Column B

For Each c In LookupRange 'Loop through range
    If c.Value <> "" Then 'If value in B is not empty then

     Cells(c.Row, 15).FormulaR1C1 = "=""""&RC[-11]&"" ""&RC[-6]&"" (MK NO. 
     ""&RC[-13]&"")"""

     Cells(c.Row, 14).FormulaR1C1 = "=""""&RC[-11]&"""""


     End If
Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

This part of the code is used to copy just the values of those cells.

```
Sub CommandButton_CopyNumbers()

Dim LastR As Long

'FIND LAST ROW OF DATA IN COLUMN N
LastR = Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row


Range("K9:N &LastR").Select 'This part is not working
Selection.Copy

End Sub
```

The first code works good, but is there a way to just set those cells equal to a value instead of a formula and copying them to the clipboard??

Comment: I don't want to paste the values. I just want it to copy to clipboard so that they can be manually pasted into a different spreadsheet. The problem with this is, the user is not used to pasting values. Instead, they just paste, which gives you the formula instead of the actual value of the cell being copied.

Comment: `Range("K9:N" & LastR)`

Comment: Only values alone?  What about formatting etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sub routine and set the shortcut key to "ctrl + v" simulating the default paste short cut.

With this, we are going to replace the default paste shortcut with the new procedure which will paste only the values of the copied selection.

```
Sub PasteAsValues()
'Set the shortcut to "ctrl + v"

Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Correct code:

```
Sub CommandButton_CopyNumbers()

Dim LastR As Long

'FIND LAST ROW OF DATA IN COLUMN N
LastR = Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row

Range("K9:N" & LastR).Select 'This part is not working
Selection.Copy

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
CopyOnlyValues Range("K9:N" & LastR)
```

Sub to copy range as text:

```
Sub CopyOnlyValues(rng As Range)
    'requires project reference to "Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library"
    Dim txt, rw As Range, objDat As New DataObject
    Dim c As Range, sepV As String, sepL

    sepL = ""
    For Each rw In rng.Rows
        sepV = ""
        For Each c In rw.Cells
            txt = txt & sepV & c.Value
            sepV = vbTab
        Next c
        txt = txt & vbLf
    Next rw

    objDat.SetText txt
    objDat.PutInClipboard
End Sub
```

Note: performance might not be great on a very large range.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Sub CommandButton_CopyNumbers()

    Dim LastR As Long
    Dim vDB As Variant
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    'FIND LAST ROW OF DATA IN COLUMN N
    LastR = Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row

    Set Ws = Sheets("Different Worksheet name")

    vDB = Range("K9:N" & LastR)

    Set Target = Ws.Range("a1") 'set your cell one
    Target.Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB

End Sub
```